# how to implement signalR hub client method having more than 5 parameters at android client side

Tags: android, signalr

This is `signalR hub` code.
How to implement `signalR hub` client method having more than 5 parameters at android client side

```
    public void SendToSpecific(string sSenderSuid, string sSenderName, string sMessage, object objImage, string stoDelimited, string sGroupSuid, long nPriority)
    {
        string[] arrDelimited = MDLIB.Global.ASGetDelimUnjoinedStrings(stoDelimited);
        foreach (string grpEntitysuid in arrDelimited)
        {
            foreach (string entry in _connections.GetConnections(grpEntitysuid))
            {
                Clients.Client(entry).broadcastMessage(sSenderSuid, sSenderName, sMessage, objImage, sGroupSuid, DateTime.UtcNow, nPriority, grpEntitysuid);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about serializing all your parameters under a single one?

Comment: thanks for comment.I cant do changes in hub code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> I found solution .Actually It was simple
> ```

```
   Subscription subscriptionBroadcastMessage = mHubProxy.subscribe(client_broadcastMessage);
            subscriptionBroadcastMessage.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>() {
                @Override
                public void run(JsonElement[] jsonElements) throws Exception {
                    System.out.print(jsonElements.toString());
                    String sSenderSuid = jsonElements[0].getAsString();
                    String sSenderName = jsonElements[1].getAsString();
                    String sMessage = jsonElements[2].getAsString();

                    }
                }
            });
```